# Can you please show me a final atomic model which demonstrates movement of electrons inside it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, subatomic

Is there any final model of an atom, of which we can say, “This is it”! Or is it still improving and physicists are not completely sure about it? I am particularly interested to know how exactly electrons move inside an atom. Do the physicists have any actual image or video of electron orbitals?

Comment: A "final solution" doesn't exist. And luckily so!

Comment: that question lacks research from the OP

Comment: @user248881 The point _aaaaa says reinstate Monica_ made is about the Stackexchange network encouraging questions which show some effort. This also applies concerning prior research on the question asked. In your case, the question is indeed interesting, but I bet just typing "final atomic model" into Google would lead to a lot of related material and would lead to a more precise question of yours (e.g. "is this particular atomic model final or where it lacks to represent the physical world") instead of the current, very broad formulation.

Comment: @user248881 "silly" is not the same as "lacking effort" See here for more: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6001/closing-insufficient-effort-questions

Comment: Given the way this question was clarified, I don't think this was the intent, but the title of the question by itself seems to indicate that the OP is asking for the historical final model of the atom before quantum mechanics came around.  As far as I know, that is the Bohr model, but I'd be interested in finding out if there were any newer ones prior to quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Electrons do not move inside atoms.

If an electron is in a given energy level $E$, the wavefunction is given by $\psi(x,y) = \phi(x)_{n\ell m} \,\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}E t/\hbar}$. The time dependence is a pure phase factor, hence the real-space probability density of the electron is $|\psi(x)|^2 = |\phi(x)|^2 \neq f(t)$, not a function of time. These are called *stationary states*, for this reason.

The fact that electrons do not actually move in atoms is **good**, and it's the whole point quantum mechanics was invented. If they were to move, they would be accelerating charged particles and would thereby lose energy to radiation (bremsstrahlung) eventually collapsing. The instability of the atom was exactly the shortcoming of classical physics that led to the invention/discovery of quantum mechanics.

Furthermore:

Atomic orbitals are only "correct"$^\dagger$ wave functions in one-electron systems such as the hydrogen atom. In many-electron atoms, orbitals are a useful approximation, usually a basis used for perturbative calculations. For instance, for Helium you already have to take into account the indistinguishability of the two electrons, which leads to the linear combinations of the orbitals to work out correction terms.

In the Hydrogen atom, the orbitals have been indirectly observed, see [Hydrogen Atoms under Magnification: Direct Observation of the Nodal Structure of Stark States](https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.213001), by recording the diffraction pattern of light radiating away from atomic transitions: these patterns related to the nodal structure of the atomic wavefunctions.

Angular-resolved photoemission spectroscopy (APRES) can give information on the shape of molecular orbitals, see [Exploring three-dimensional orbital imagingwith energy-dependent photoemission tomography](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms9287.pdf).

$\dagger$: but only within the pure Coulomb Hamiltonian. With corrections such as fine structure, Lamb shift etc., there is no analytical solution for both eigenvalues and eigenstates.

**EDIT from comments**.

Given the attention this answer has got, let me add a few points raised in the long discussion that ensued in the comments.

First and foremost, the above answer reflects my opinion and my interpretation of the matter. Indeed, as @my2cts points out:

> Whether electrons move or not is pure interpretation. What QM does
>   unequivocally say is that electrons have kinetic and potential energy.
>   Anyone is free to interpret this.

Then, regarding *motion*, it is true that electrons possess momentum, kinetic energy, and, for $\ell \neq s$, a probability current $\mathbf{J}$ that is however also stationary but in the tangential direction $\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$ (derivation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270347/does-angular-momentum-of-hydrogen-atom-imply-motion-of-electron-around-the-nucle/270460#270460)) like the velocity of a classically orbiting object.

Particularly, @dmckee says:

> the electrons have a well defined energy which has to be interpreted
>   as including a kinetic component and a momentum distribution which may
>   include zero but also includes non-zero value with non-trivial
>   probability density.

My idea of "electrons do not move" stems from the idea that "standing waves do not move", in that they don't go from A to B. But of course there is motion nonetheless. See [nice discussion here](https://wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2014/12/01/does-an-electron-in-an-atom-move-at-all/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102962/discussion-on-answer-by-superciocia-can-you-please-show-me-a-final-atomic-model).

Answer (score 24):

There are no final models in science, there's always room for improvement. And major paradigm shifts cannot be totally ruled out. However, we can be quite confident in our current model of the electronic structure of the atom, which is based on quantum electrodynamics (QED), which has been validated to very high precision.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital) has numerous orbital *diagrams*, including many animated ones. But you also need to read the text to understand how the diagrams work, and even then, it's not easy to understand what's going on unless you've studied some quantum mechanics, and are familiar with the basic concepts, and some of the mathematics.

I'm quite fond of the animated diagrams in the section titled [Qualitative understanding of shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Qualitative_understanding_of_shapes):

> The shapes of atomic orbitals can be qualitatively understood by considering the analogous case of standing waves on a circular drum
>
> [...]
>
> The basic reason for this correspondence lies in the fact that the distribution of kinetic energy and momentum in a matter-wave is predictive of where the particle associated with the wave will be. That is, the probability of finding an electron at a given place is also a function of the electron's average momentum at that point, since high electron momentum at a given position tends to "localize" the electron in that position, via the properties of electron wave-packets (see the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_uncertainty_principle) for details of the mechanism).

We can make images & even movies of actual orbitals, but they're rather crude; the diagrams are better. I suppose that the images & movies are beneficially in that they demonstrate to the lay audience that the diagrams are valid, and not just some mathematical fabrication. ;)

---

It is not easy to appreciate exactly how electrons move inside the atom. Things at the quantum scale simply do not behave in the way we are accustomed to at the macroscopic scale, so our normal intuitions aren't much help when it comes to electrons. That does *not* mean that these things are incomprehensible, but it does mean that we can mislead ourselves if we try to apply classical notions to these decidedly non-classical entities.

So while electrons in atoms certainly have kinetic energy and momentum (including orbital angular momentum, apart from electrons in *s* orbitals), it's a mistake to ascribe any kind of classical trajectory to them.

Answer (score 7):

What we have is Quantum Mechanics  supplemented by Quantum Electrodynamics. With the tools available you can calculate atomic properties to increasing accuracy. Neutral hydrogen can be treated by the Schrödinger and more accurately the Dirac equation. Then you can throw in perturbative QED radiative corrections and a finite size nucleus. This brings you to the limit or beyond experimental accuracy. For many-electron atoms you also have to consider configuration interaction and corrections to the Born approximation. This is quite final in my opinion.

Comment: Now, thát's something useful!

Comment: Yeah but does that mean electrons move or is it the opposite?

Comment: @Renan Electrons don't move. That is to say, not in continuous trajectories. They jump discontinuously around in their shell, together with the other indistinguishable electrons in that shell (but independently of the electrons in other shells, if they are there). So they DO move but in a fast and jumpy way, so it seems like a cloud.

Comment: @descheleschilder Can you define what you mean when you say that electrons don't move? Can you give an accurate account of how "they jump discontinuously around in their shells"? I suspect it is just how you picture it. There is nothing in physics that supports such conclusions.

Comment: I said that they DO move. But not in a classic way. They move in a quantum way: discontinuously, and randomly. That's why every orbital has a certain energy or discrete (quantum!) angular momentum (in whatever direction, which becomes certain after a measurement). What else can I say?

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to have **the** final model of an atom. We'll have to do it with approximations.

Ther are simply too many factors to take into account. Even a "simple" thing as the proton spin: See [this PDF](http://vixra.org/pdf/1703.0061v1.pdf) for example.

And, depending on the kind of atom, there is at least 1 proton to find in every atom. And don't forget the neutrons (both nucleons). and the interaction between them. The spin-orbit couplings. Etc.etc.

For the proton-electron system (Hydrogen) the best approximation can be made. Simply because it's the most simple atom. Three quarks (proton), one electron. 
It is already difficult though (even with the aid of a supercomputer) to calculate the interactions between the valence quarks and the non-valence quarks by means of gluons (see the PDF).
When this is done you have to calculate the interaction between the proton and the electron. Not **that** difficult (by means of the Schrodinger equation), but when you try to do it in
connection with QED the story becomes somewhat more difficult.

So you can imagine how the situation is for higher mass atoms!

About the visibility of atoms.
It will never ever be possible to see how an atom looks like (in whatever way)! Maybe a computer-generated image, which is something different. Don't get fooled by people (writing for sensational magazines, to get the money coming in) who say they can. Look at this one:

[First Atom made Visible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ialegYl3cko)

Again, don't let these popularizations fool you! You **don't see** the atoms, but an image of them, which is something completely different. Imagine you had the size in the order of atoms. How would you be able to see them? By shining photons on them? No. I think you are intelligent enough to see why this is impossible.

One more but the last thing. It is said in one answer here that QED is used in all calculations concerning the atom. NOT true.  @my2cts addresses this issue perfectly.

Comment: _"I think you are intelligent enough to see why this is impossible."_ — Apparently, I'm not intelligent enough. Please elaborate why having the size of the order of atoms would make it impossible for me to emit photons. If hydrogen can, why can't I?

Comment: @Ruslan, a single atom can be made visible by immobilising it and shining an extremely high intensity light on it, which is what ion trap experiements do. What they do not do is allow you to see any detail of the structure of the atom, because the wavelength of the light is greater than the size of the atom. You can see it in the sense that you can see Polaris, but not in the sense that you can see the Sistine Chapel.

Comment: @Ruslan You can't see the atom, even in an ion trap, like Ben rightly said. And besides, what do you think the high-intensity light will do with it? Anyway, you can't see them directly, only an image of them (with computer-generated colors). Hai capito?

Comment: @Ruslan I don't understand though what you are asking exactly. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Ruslan Of course, you can't be that little. And IF you are who said that YOU can't emit photons. We can turn it around too and blow up the atom to our size, but then you get crazy!!! The other way round too, by the way. So why bother?

Comment: There're some ways a small object could see an atom, even with photons. Screw the atom after this, it's done its purpose. E.g. let there be a tiny gamma-sensitive photographic sensor and a source of gamma photons on the opposite sides of an atom. Let the gamma photons burst and hit the sensor. Some of these photons will be scattered on the electrons and the nucleus. The sensor will have corresponding dips in recorded intensity. That's it: the sensor has seen the atom (which was destroyed in the course, but who cares).

Comment: @Ruslan Hi, I'm back. In the example you give, it's a question of what the balance is. The balance between how many gamma photons you need to record (which is different from seeing but alas) the dips and how many you need to blow the atom to smithereens. If the balance is in favor of the recording, it will be a 2-d record. How will the record look like? Won't the dips occur randomly after being scattered?

Comment: The dips will represent measurement of the positions of scattering centers — atom's electrons and nucleus. Of course they will be random, since the particles don't have definite positions. Also, nothing prevents one from having two simultaneously triggered sources of photons and two sensors: then you can get a stereo image (which is the best kind of 3D vision normally accessible to a human). This would work because of their simultaneity: measurement of position in quick succession is bound to give consistent results (see [quantum zeno effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_zeno_effect)).

Comment: So the patterns emerge, dip by a dip. Now that's a great experiment. What's your source?

Comment: @Ruslan This would be a great experiment! Has it ever been done?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to understand the difference between orbit and orbital. Originally the atom was imagined with classical orbits (like planets around stars), but eventually QM was developed and now we talk about electron orbitals.

> In atomic theory and quantum mechanics, an atomic orbital is a mathematical function that describes the wave-like behavior of either one electron or a pair of electrons in an atom.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4uX5.jpg) This function can be used to calculate the probability of finding any electron of an atom in any specific region around the atom's nucleus. The term atomic orbital may also refer to the physical region or space where the electron can be calculated to be present, as defined by the particular mathematical form of the orbital.[2]

Now today, we have basically three types of orbitals:

1. Hydrogen like
2. Slater Type
3. Gaussian type

So basically the current atomic orbital models describe the electrons' existence around the nucleus as a probability distribution. Now you are asking whether these have certain shapes? Yes they do.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital

Comment: Do those orbitals move inside an atom? And if i am not wrong then a pair of electrons never move inside those orbitals, either as particles or as waves. The only time, an electron move is when it gets excited by a photon of typical wavelength and then electron jump into a higher orbital, am i right?

Comment: @user248881 correct, as per QM, the electrons do not classically move, they exist at certain probabilities. Though, even when the electron gets excited, it does not classically move to another orbit, but it starts existing first in a superposition of the two orbitals, and then smoothly it changes to the new orbital. I actually asked a question about this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488527/do-electrons-really-perform-instantaneous-quantum-leaps?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does electron jump from one energy level to another energy level happens between orbitals or between subshells or between shells? Do orbitals or subshells or shells rotates around nucleus of an atom? I am sorry for these silly questions but i want to clear the concept of an atom in my mind.

Comment: @user248881 electrons do not jump, they smoothly go from one state to another, with a superposition between the two orbitals. Excitation is usually referred to as between orbitals.

Comment: You still don’t answer this question. - “Do orbitals or subshells or shells rotates around nucleus of an atom?”

Comment: @user248881 can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: If i am not wrong, every atom has a single nucleus. Now, this nucleus is always at it’s center and it is always surrounded orbitals which contains an electron or a pair of electrons. Now, what i want to know is, does an orbital always remain fixed in reference to the nucleus or does it change it’s position in reference to nucleus?

Comment: @user248881 the specific orbitals are the intrinsic properties of atoms, and they usually do not change (for a ground state atom).

Comment: @user248881 You ask yourself if the orbitals, shells, or subshells are rotating. They have angular momentum, yes. But this doesn't mean they are actually rotating around the nucleus. Then you look at the atom in a classical way. Which can't be done (maybe for a human-sized atom...). The electrons jump around (in each subshell or shell, independently from the ones in other orbitals. Very fast, discontinuously and randomly. They look therefore like clouds. The angular momentum (energy) depends on the orbital, and have discrete directions, which are realized after a measurement.